# Jacoco-Not excluding files

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using Gradle and Jacoco. This is my `build.gradle` :

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                    '**/TrackingDataRecord.java'
                    ])
        })
    }
}
test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.jacocoTestReport)
```

I am trying to exclude that java file but it still shows the coverage on SonarQube. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle task `jacocoTestReport` generates XML/HTML/CSV report by analysing JaCoCo `exec` file and Java `class` files.

SonarQube doesn't use reports generated by Gradle task `jacocoTestReport`, instead it also generates its own report by analysing JaCoCo `exec` file and Java `class` files - as a proof quote from https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project :

> ```
> | Property                 | Example            | Description
> | sonar.jacoco.reportPaths | target/jacoco.exec | Import JaCoCo code coverage reports. Set the property to the path of the JaCoCo .exec
> ```

This might change in future and SonarQube might start importing XML reports - see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1362

About exclusions in SonarQube see https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus :

> Ignore Code Coverage
>
> You can prevent some files from being taken into account for code coverage by unit tests.
>
> To do so, go to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Code Coverage and set the Coverage Exclusions property.